# How to load 'custom-header.php' from child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child

So I've created a child theme in WordPress, and everything works as it should except for the custom-header.php. I wish to use the one in the child theme, not the one in the parent theme. I am doing this by attempting to call it from the functions.php file in my child theme. **I have my child theme's custom-header.php file in an inc folder, but have tried it in the main directory with the rest of the files.**

### **My Code (functions.php)**

```
<?php
/**
* Enqueues child theme stylesheet, loading first the parent theme stylesheet.
*/
function nisarg_custom_enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nisarg_custom_enqueue_child_theme_styles', 11 );

/* Problem Code Below */
require_once( get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/custom-header.php' );
```

### **The Problem**

The problem is this line: `require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php' );` Whenever I put any `require_once` statement in my functions.php file, the entire website goes blank.

### **My Question**

How can I load my child theme's custom-header.php instead of the parent theme's?

### **Error Log**

```
[Tue May 23 11:54:12.128948 2017] [:error] [pid 30729] [client 192.168.1.1:53819] PHP Warning:  require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /var/www/1to1/wp/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nisarg-child/functions.php on line 11
[Tue May 23 11:54:12.129019 2017] [:error] [pid 30729] [client 192.168.1.1:53819] PHP Warning:  require_once(http://conradbowenrealestate.com/wp-content/themes/nisarg/inc/custom-header.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /var/www/1to1/wp/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nisarg-child/functions.php on line 11
[Tue May 23 11:54:12.129039 2017] [:error] [pid 30729] [client 192.168.1.1:53819] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://conradbowenrealestate.com/wp-content/themes/nisarg/inc/custom-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/1to1/wp/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nisarg-child/functions.php on line 11
```

### **My Code (custom-header.php)**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @package Nisarg
 */

/**
 * Set up the WordPress core custom header feature.
 *
 * @uses nisarg_header_style()
 * @uses nisarg_admin_header_style()
 * @uses nisarg_admin_header_image()
 */
function nisarg_custom_header_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'nisarg_custom_header_args', array(
        'default-image'          => '',
        'default-text-color'     => 'fff',
        'width'                  => 1600,
        'height'                 => 400,
        'flex-height'            => true,
        'wp-head-callback'       => 'nisarg_header_style',
        'admin-head-callback'    => 'nisarg_admin_header_style',
        'admin-preview-callback' => 'nisarg_admin_header_image',
    ) ) );


    /*
     * Default custom headers packaged with the theme.
     * %s is a placeholder for the theme template directory URI.
     */
    register_default_headers( array(
        'mountains' => array(
            'url'           => '%s/images/headers/mountains.png',
            'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/mountains_thumbnail.png',
            'description'   => _x( 'food', 'header image description', 'nisarg' )
        ),  
        'skyline' => array(
            'url'           => '%s/images/headers/skyline.png',
            'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/skyline_thumbnail.png',
            'description'   => _x( 'buildings', 'header image description', 'nisarg' )
        ),
        'sea' => array(
            'url'           => '%s/images/headers/sea.png',
            'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/sea_thumbnail.png',
            'description'   => _x( 'Wood', 'header image description', 'nisarg' )
        ),
        'food' => array(
            'url'           => '%s/images/headers/food.png',
            'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/food_thumbnail.png',
            'description'   => _x( 'food', 'header image description', 'nisarg' )
        ),      
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'nisarg_custom_header_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'nisarg_header_style' ) ) :
/**
 * Styles the header image and text displayed on the blog
 *
 * @see nisarg_custom_header_setup().
 */
function nisarg_header_style() {
    $header_image = get_header_image();
    $header_text_color   = get_header_textcolor();

    // If no custom options for text are set, let's bail.
    if ( empty( $header_image ) && $header_text_color == get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-color' ) ){
        return;
    }

    // If we get this far, we have custom styles.
    ?>
    <style type="text/css" id="nisarg-header-css">
    <?php
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
            $header_width = get_custom_header()->width;
            $header_height = get_custom_header()->height;
            $header_height1 = ($header_height / $header_width * 1600);
            $header_height2 = ($header_height / $header_width * 768);
            $header_height3 = ($header_height / $header_width * 360);

    ?>
                .site-header {
                    background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) no-repeat scroll top;
                    <?php if($header_height1 > 575){ ?>
                        background-size: 100% auto;
                        padding-bottom:44%
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                        background-size: 1600px 575px;
                        height: 575px;
                    <?php } ?>
                }

                @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
                    .site-header {
                        <?php if($header_height2 > 170){ ?>
                            background-size: 1024px auto;
                            height: <?php echo $header_height2;?>px;
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                            background-size: 1024px 170px;
                            height: 170px;
                        <?php } ?>              
                    }
                }

                @media (max-width: 767px) {
                    .site-header {
                        <?php if($header_height2 > 170){ ?>
                            background-size: 768px auto;
                            height: <?php echo $header_height2;?>px;
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                            background-size: 768px 170px;
                            height: 170px;
                        <?php } ?>              
                    }
                }
                @media (max-width: 359px) {
                    .site-header {
                        <?php if($header_height3 > 80){ ?>
                            background-size: 768px auto;
                            height: <?php echo $header_height3;?>px;
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                            background-size: 768px 80px;
                            height: 80px;
                        <?php } ?>

                    }

                }
                .site-header{
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                }
  <?php else: ?>
    .site-header{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
    }
    .site-header {
            height: 300px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            .site-header {
                height: 200px;
            }
        }
        @media (max-width: 359px) {
            .site-header {
                height: 150px;
            }
        }

    <?php endif; 

        // Has the text been hidden?
        if ( ! display_header_text() ) :

    ?>
        .site-title,
        .site-description {
            position: absolute;
            clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE7 */
            clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
        }
    <?php
        endif;
        if ( empty( $header_image ) ) :
    ?>
        .site-header .home-link {
            min-height: 0;
        }
    <?php

        // If the user has set a custom color for the text, use that.

        else:

    ?>

        .site-title,
        .site-description {
            color: #<?php echo esc_attr( $header_text_color ); ?>;
        }
        .site-title::after{
            background: #<?php echo esc_attr( $header_text_color ); ?>;
            content:"";       
        }
    <?php endif; ?>

    </style>
    <?php
}
endif; // nisarg_header_style


if ( ! function_exists( 'nisarg_admin_header_style' ) ) :

/**
 * Styles the header image displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.
 *
 * @see nisarg_custom_header_setup().
 */
function nisarg_admin_header_style() {
?>
    <?php
        if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() || '' == get_header_textcolor() )
            $style = ' style="display:none;"';
        else
            $style = ' style="color:#' . get_header_textcolor() . ';"';
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .appearance_page_custom-header #headimg{
            background: #fff;
            border: none;
        }

        #headimg .site-branding {
            margin:0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-right: -50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            text-align: center;
        }


        #headimg h1 { /* This is the site title displayed in the preview */
            <?php echo esc_attr($style); ?>
            text-transform: uppercase; 
            letter-spacing: 10px;
        }

        #headimg a{
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #headimg #desc{
            <?php echo esc_attr($style); ?>
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 0.2em 0em;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
        #headimg .home-link .displaying-header-text::after{
            background: #<?php get_header_textcolor() ?>;
            content:"";
            height: 2px;
            display: block;
            width: 20%;
            margin: 5px auto;
        }
    </style>
<?php
}
endif; // nisarg_admin_header_style

if ( ! function_exists( 'nisarg_admin_header_image' ) ) :
/**
 * Custom header image markup displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.
 *
 * @see nisarg_custom_header_setup().
 */
function nisarg_admin_header_image() {
?>

<?php
        if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() || '' == get_header_textcolor() )
            $style = ' style="color: #fff;"';
        else
            $style = ' style="color:#' . get_header_textcolor() . ';"';

        ?>

    <div id="headimg">      
        <div class="site-branding">
            <div class="home-link">

                <h1 class="displaying-header-text"><a id="name" style="<?php echo esc_attr( $style ); ?>" onclick="return false;" href="<?php esc_url('#'); ?>" tabindex="-1"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <h2 id="desc" class="displaying-header-text" style="<?php echo esc_attr( $style ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $header_image = get_header_image();
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                .site-header {
                    background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) no-repeat scroll top;
                }
            </style>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(''!= get_header_textcolor() || 'blank' != get_header_textcolor()){ ?>
                <style type="text/css">
                #headimg h1::after{
                background: #<?php get_header_textcolor() ?>;
                content:"";
                height: 2px;
                display: block;
                width: 20%;
                margin: 5px auto;
                }       
            </style>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
endif; // nisarg_admin_header_image
```

**All code posted in this question is from the child theme.**

Comment: please show the problematic custom-header.php file content

Comment: @DRC The custom-header.php file works fine when I put it in the parent theme's inc folder. The problem is I can't load it in the child theme. But I'll go ahead and post the code anyway.

Comment: Check with firebug (F12) to see if its loading the css file and if you have the path of the php file correct, plus I think you are loading the php file into the head since you're using enqueue scripts for this

Comment: Check your error log or turn on error reporting.

Comment: @K.Tromp Not sure what firebug is, but that pulls up inspector for me. I'll see if I notice anything there.

Comment: @NathanDawson I added the relevant error log info

Comment: @Spencer4134 answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to require a file using a URL instead of a path. `get_template_directory_uri()` will return the URL to the parent theme folder.

You need `get_stylesheet_directory()` to get the path to the child theme.

Replace this:

```
require_once( get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/custom-header.php' );
```

With:

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php' );
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please go through the below following steps, may helps you**

For example Your child theme is **{parent theme name}-child**

**Step-1:** Your child theme **style.css** file should be like this

```
/* 
Theme Name:      {Parent theme name} Child Theme 
Theme URI:       http://www.example.com/
Description:     Theme by Site <a href=\"http://www.example.com//\">http://childthemegenerator.com/</a>
Author:          some XYZ
Author URI:      http://childthemegenerator.com/
Template:        {Parent theme name}
Version:         1.0.0
Text Domain:     {Parent theme name}-child
-------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

/* =Theme customization starts here
------------------------------------------------------- */
```

**Step-2:** Override your parent theme **"inc/custom-header.php"** into child theme **"inc/custom-header.php"**

**Step-3:** Edit the child theme **"inc/custom-header.php"** file of each function, because these function already defined in parent theme **"inc/custom-header.php"**.

Same functions are using in your child theme **"inc/custom-header.php"** file. This is the reason you are getting **website goes blank**.

So you should rename each and every fnction of the child theme **"inc/custom-header.php"** file and save it. I have already renamed each function in the child theme **"inc/custom-header.php"** file.

The child theme **"inc/custom-header.php"** file should be like this

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @package Nisarg Child Theme 
 */

/**
 * Set up the WordPress core custom header feature.
 *
 * @uses nisarg_child_header_style()
 * @uses nisarg_child_admin_header_style()
 * @uses nisarg_child_admin_header_image()
 */
function nisarg_child_custom_header_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'nisarg_child_custom_header_args', array(
        'default-image'          => '',
        'default-text-color'     => 'fff',
        'width'                  => 1600,
        'height'                 => 400,
        'flex-height'            => true,
        'wp-head-callback'       => 'nisarg_child_header_style',
        'admin-head-callback'    => 'nisarg_child_admin_header_style',
        'admin-preview-callback' => 'nisarg_child_admin_header_image',
    ) ) );

    /*
     * Default custom headers packaged with the theme.
     * %s is a placeholder for the theme template directory URI.
     */
    register_default_headers( array(
        'mountains' => array(
            'url'           => '%s/images/headers/mountains.png',
            'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/mountains_thumbnail.png',
            'description'   => _x( 'food', 'header image description', 'nisarg' ),
        ),
        'skyline' => array(
            'url'           => '%s/images/headers/skyline.png',
            'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/skyline_thumbnail.png',
            'description'   => _x( 'buildings', 'header image description', 'nisarg' ),
        ),
        'sea' => array(
            'url'           => '%s/images/headers/sea.png',
            'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/sea_thumbnail.png',
            'description'   => _x( 'Wood', 'header image description', 'nisarg' ),
        ),
        'food' => array(
            'url'           => '%s/images/headers/food.png',
            'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/food_thumbnail.png',
            'description'   => _x( 'food', 'header image description', 'nisarg' ),
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'nisarg_child_custom_header_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'nisarg_child_header_style' ) ) :
    /**
     * Styles the header image and text displayed on the blog
     *
     * @see nisarg_custom_header_setup().
     */
    function nisarg_child_header_style() {
        $header_image = get_header_image();
        $header_text_color   = get_header_textcolor();
        // If no custom options for text are set, let's bail.
        if ( empty( $header_image ) && $header_text_color == get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-

color' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // If we get this far, we have custom styles.
        ?>
        <style type="text/css" id="nisarg-header-css">
        <?php
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
            $header_width = get_custom_header()->width;
            $header_height = get_custom_header()->height;
            $header_height320 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 320 );
            $header_height360 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 360 );
            $header_height768 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 768 );
            $header_height980 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 980 );
            $header_height1280 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 1280 );
            $header_height1366 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 1366 );
            $header_height1440 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 1440 );
            $header_height1600 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 1600 );
            $header_height1920 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 1920 );
            $header_height2560 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 2560 );
            $header_height2880 = ( $header_height / $header_width * 2880 );
            ?>
            .site-header {
                background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) no-repeat scroll top;
                background-size: cover;
            }
            @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 359px ) {
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height320 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px ) {
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height360 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px ) {
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height768 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1279px ){
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height980 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1365px ){
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height1280 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1439px ){
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height1366 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1599px ) {
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height1440 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 1919px ) {
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height1600 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2559px ) {
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height1920 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 2560px)  and (max-width: 2879px ) {
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height2560 );?>px;
                }
            }
            @media (min-width: 2880px) {
                .site-header {
                    height: <?php echo absint( $header_height2880 );?>px;
                }
            }
            .site-header{
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
            }
        <?php else : ?>
            .site-header{
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(182,182,182,0.3);
            }
            .site-header {
                    height: 300px;
                }
                @media (max-width: 767px) {
                    .site-header {
                        height: 200px;
                    }
                }
                @media (max-width: 359px) {
                    .site-header {
                        height: 150px;
                    }
                }
        <?php endif;
        // Has the text been hidden?
        if ( ! display_header_text() ) :
        ?>
            .site-title,
            .site-description {
                position: absolute;
                clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE7 */
                clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
            }
        <?php
        endif;
        if ( empty( $header_image ) ) :
            ?>
            .site-header .home-link {
                min-height: 0;
            }
            <?php
            // If the user has set a custom color for the text, use that.
        else : ?>
            .site-title,
            .site-description {
                color: #<?php echo esc_attr( $header_text_color ); ?>;
            }
            .site-title::after{
                background: #<?php echo esc_attr( $header_text_color ); ?>;
                content:"";
            }
        <?php endif; ?>
        </style>
        <?php
    }
endif; // nisarg_child_header_style


if ( ! function_exists( 'nisarg_child_admin_header_style' ) ) :
    /**
     * Styles the header image displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.
     *
     * @see nisarg_custom_header_setup().
     */
    function nisarg_child_admin_header_style() {
    ?>
        <?php
        if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() || '' == get_header_textcolor() ) {
            $style = ' style="display:none;"';
        } else {
            $style = ' style="color:#' . get_header_textcolor() . ';"';
        }
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .appearance_page_custom-header #headimg{
                background: #fff;
                border: none;
            }

            #headimg .site-branding {
                margin:0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-right: -50%;
                -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                text-align: center;
            }
            #headimg h1 { /* This is the site title displayed in the preview */
                <?php echo esc_attr( $style ); ?>
                text-transform: uppercase;
                letter-spacing: 10px;
            }

            #headimg a{
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            #headimg #desc{
                <?php echo esc_attr( $style ); ?>
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 0.2em 0em;
                letter-spacing: 5px;
                text-transform: capitalize;
            }
            #headimg .home-link .displaying-header-text::after{
                background: #<?php get_header_textcolor() ?>;
                content:"";
                height: 2px;
                display: block;
                width: 20%;
                margin: 5px auto;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
    }
endif; // nisarg_child_admin_header_style

if ( ! function_exists( 'nisarg_child_admin_header_image' ) ) :
    /**
     * Custom header image markup displayed on the Appearance > Header admin panel.
     *
     * @see nisarg_child_custom_header_setup().
     */
    function nisarg_child_admin_header_image() {
        if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() || '' == get_header_textcolor() ) {
            $style = ' style="color: #fff;"';
        } else {
            $style = ' style="color:#' . get_header_textcolor() . ';"';
        } ?>
    <div id="headimg">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <div class="home-link">
                <h1 class="displaying-header-text"><a id="name" style="<?php echo esc_attr( $style ); ?>" 

onclick="return false;" href="<?php esc_url('#'); ?>" tabindex="-1"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <h2 id="desc" class="displaying-header-text" style="<?php echo esc_attr( $style ); ?>"><?

php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $header_image = get_header_image();
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                .site-header {
                    background: url(<?php header_image(); ?>) no-repeat scroll top;
                }
            </style>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( '' != get_header_textcolor() || 'blank' != get_header_textcolor() ) { ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                #headimg h1::after{
                    background: #<?php get_header_textcolor() ?>;
                    content:"";
                    height: 2px;
                    display: block;
                    width: 20%;
                    margin: 5px auto;
                }
            </style>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
endif; // nisarg_child_admin_header_image
```

**Step-4:** Your child theme **fnctions.php** should be like this

```
<?php 
     add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
     function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { 
          wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); 
          } 


      require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php' );            

 ?>
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you mean by step 2. I did everything else though, and it still shows up blank. I also removed the closing ?> tag in the functions.php file, as it's not there originally and is probably in a different file.

Comment: In parent theme "inc" folder you have "custom-header.php" file, you can copy and paste that file into child theme "inc" folder.

Comment: Your child theme folder structre should be like this root/wp-content/themes/{childtheme-folder}

Comment: The child theme folder structure or files should be--------> style.css, functions.php, inc/custom-header.php. These 3 files only I have given above post.

Comment: That's exactly how I have my child theme setup. Everything in the child theme works as it should except for the "custom-header.php"

Comment: I followed your steps exactly and it hasn't changed the outcome :/

Answer (score 1):

It helps you by using the **get_header()** fnction

Your custom header name should be like this **"header-name.php"**, then call custom header name in that function.

```
<?php get_header('name'); ?>
```

Comment: I'll try this next time I get into the office. Note that this isn't the main header file, nor is it replacing the main header file. There's "header.php", and then there's "custom-header.php". Both are made by WordPress, and I'm just trying to make my own "custom-header.php" in a child theme overwrite the parent theme.

Comment: Ok, I have added another post. Please look in to that post